# The “Home” section of my Facebook page is empty (on mobile only)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

The Facebook home section seems to be empty and I don't understand why... out of 3 pages I have, 2 of them does this. I don't get it because they all have the same option activated and it seems like there is no real logic behind it...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was only a bug from Facebook, I did nothing but report it to Facebook and now it works like a charm !